# Is SQL IN Query better for performance or Java method ContainsAll

Tags: java, sql

I have a scenario where user will select bulk of input up to 100K entries and i need to validate if this data belongs to the user and satisfies other X conditions so should I use complex Oracle SQL DB query - composite IN(id,column) to validate it OR

Should I fetch the data for this user satisfying the conditions  to application memory and use List.containsAll, by first getting all the data (with all the other conditions)for this particular user and populating it in a dbList and then validating dbList.containsAll(inputList).

Which one will be better performace wise. DB Composite IN to send bulk input vs get the input and validate it with containsAll

I tried running SQL query in SIT environment, the query is taking around 70 -90 seconds which is too bad. It would be better in prod but still I feel the data has to sort through huge data in DB even though it is indexed by user ID.

IN DB i am using Count(*) with IN like below :

```
SQL Query :
select count(*) from user_table where user_id='X123' and X condtions  and user_input IN(
('id','12344556'),
('id','789954334')
('id','343432443')
('id','455543545')
------- 50k entries
);
```

Also there are other AND conditions as well for validating the user_input are valid entries.

Sample JAVA code:

```
List<String> userInputList = request.getInputList();
List<String> userDBList = sqlStatement.execute(getConditionedQuery);
Boolean validDate = userDBList.containsAll(userInputList );

getConditionedQuery = "select user_backedn_id from user_table where user_id='X123'AND X complex conditions";
```

The SQL Query with composite IN condition takes around 70-90 seconds in lower environments, however Java code for the containsALL looks much faster.

Incidentally, I don't want to use temp table and execute the procedure because again bulk input entry in DB is a hassle. I am using ATG framework and the module is RESTful so performance is most important here.

Comment: how you obtain  the IN content ???

Comment: @scaisEdge : from the user input.

Comment: @Mir    100K form user input?  explain better  i don't understant.. which db you are really using ?? some db have a limit for IN content  dimension

Comment: Oracle sql , I have tried SQL Composite IN query for 60k records, it has a limit of 100k. This much data can come for scenarios where user selected a UI flag "select all",( which i can handle by taking the parameter for which the select all is given and filter from DB on that,) and then un checks few, the input can be quite large.

Answer (score 2):

I personally believe that you should apply all filters at the database side only for many reasons. First, exchanging that much data over the network will consume unnecessary bandwidth. Second, bringing all that data into JVM and processing it will consume more memory. Third, databases can be tuned and optimised for complex queries. Talk to your DBA, give him the query and him to run an analysis. The analysis will tell you if you need to add any indexes to optimise your query.

Also, contrary to your belief, my experience says that if a query takes 70-90 seconds in SIT, it will take MORE time in prod. Because although PROD machine are much faster, the amount of data in PROD is much much higher compared to SIT, so it will take longer. But that does not mean you should haul it over the network and process it in JVM. Plus, JVMs heap memory is much much lesser compared to database memory.

Also, as we move to a cloud-enabled, containerised application architecture, network bandwidth is charged. E.g. if your application is in the cloud and the database in on premise, imagine amount of data you will move back and forth to finally filter out 10 rows from a million rows.

I recommend that you write a good query, optimise it and process as many conditions as possible on the database side only. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

In general it's a good idea to push as much of the processing to the database. Even though it might actually like a bottleneck, it is generally well optimised and can work over the large amounts of data faster than you would.

For read queries like the one you're describing, you can even offload the work to read replicas, so it doesn't overwhelm the master.